# Prevent Cloud9 workspace going into idle

Tags: apache, cloud, server, cloud9-ide

**Problem:**

Trying to figure out if there is a possibility to prevent the workspace at Cloud9 from going into idle. After I work on a project and leave it for some time, it will not be accessible through the provided url from Cloud9. I have to go into Cloud9 and start the Apache server again.

**Desired solution:**

Keep workspace alive until I stop the server.

I haven't been able to find an answer to this on Google, Cloud9's website, or searching Stackoverflow.

Comment: Does this happen instantly when you log out? Since Cloud9 workspaces are basically development environments, and not geared for hosting, they will idle after a few days (depending on the plan) to preserve resources, assuming that you're no longer working on the app and hence don't need the resources right now.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to have worked for me. In the cloud9 environment, go to preferences as in the photo below, and change the stop time.

[image]